# Angular Material (2.0) AutoComplete Suggestions Panel Appears behind Bootstrap Modal

Tags: angular, autocomplete, bootstrap-modal, z-index

I'm trying to add an autocomplete field to a boostrap modal i have, but when typing the suggestions box appears behind the modal and out of view for the user.

I've tried the following:

```
.mat-autocomplete-panel {
    position: fixed !important;
    z-index:100000 !important;
}
```

But I didn't find any success, has anyone had any luck moving the suggestions box to the front?

Image:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Paste this class on your main **style.scss**

/* Mat Autocomplete on Modal Fixes */
.cdk-overlay-container {z-index: 999999 !important;}